# Add neighboring stones of the same color to form chains, with logging for isolated stones

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to check four things, one of those things might happen, maybe two, three or four things, but if none of them occur, then I want to run some code. I can't do an `else` statement because that only applies to one and I can't do `else if` because more than one can happen.

At the moment I've resorted to this:

```
function checkChains(x, y, color, array)
{
    var count = 0;

    if ((x + 1) != (boardSize) && (stones[x + 1][y] == color))
    {
        addToChain(x, y, x + 1, y, array);
    }
    else
    {
        count++;
    }

    if ((x != 0) && (stones[x - 1][y] == color))
    {
        addToChain(x, y, x - 1, y, array);
    }
    else
    {
        count++;
    }

    if ((y + 1) != (boardSize) && (stones[x][y + 1] == color))
    {
        addToChain(x, y, x, y + 1, array);
    }
        else
    {
        count++;
    }

    if ((y != 0) && (stones[x][y - 1] == color))
    {
        addToChain(x, y, x, y - 1, array);
    }
    else
    {
        count++;
    }

    if (count == 4)
    {
        console.log("none!");
    }
}
```

It's pretty ugly, can this be tidied?

Comment: Could you replace this with a more concrete example? Do you really run `addToChain(x, y, x + 1, y, array);` up to 4 times? Do you call anything in any of the elses?

Comment: Sorry thats a typo, ive changed them, the addToChain calls are slightly different. And no the only reason i have the elses is to do count++ so i can see if all 4 dont get called

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You don't really need your `else`s. Move `count++` to the if, and change your last if to `!count`.
- Rather than using `!=`, you should really use `<` and `<=`. This means you you can use `x + 1 < boardSize` rather than `(x + 1) != (boardSize)`.
- You should learn operator precedence, `==` happens before `&&`. And so you can remove even more parentheses.

And so you can use:

```
function checkChains(x, y, color, array)
{
    var count = 0;

    if (x + 1 < boardSize && stones[x + 1][y] == color)
    {
        addToChain(x, y, x + 1, y, array);
        count++;
    }

    if (x > 0 && stones[x - 1][y] == color)
    {
        addToChain(x, y, x - 1, y, array);
        count++;
    }

    if (y + 1 < boardSize && stones[x][y + 1] == color)
    {
        addToChain(x, y, x, y + 1, array);
        count++;
    }

    if (y > 0 && stones[x][y - 1] == color)
    {
        addToChain(x, y, x, y - 1, array);
        count++;
    }

    if (!count)
    {
        console.log("none!");
    }
}
```

Comment: It still has to be `x + 1 < boardSize`. To see why, run this code in any language with array bounds checks. You could also add that `===` is better than `==` and that numbers are not booleans, therefore the check should be `count === 0`.

Comment: @RolandIllig Yes you're correct, my mental maths has failed me, ): As for `===` feel free to write an answer, :) and `if (!count)` I think is perfectly idiomatic, as truthy/falsy tests are idiomatic in JavaScript.